# What is the most efficient way to create an iterative Fade-In-Out Function with jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have coded a fade-in-out function in jquery, which is working well, but looks as if there is a more elegant way to write it. The initial opacity is set to null. Here is what I have:

```
 $('span[data-i18n="text.about"]').click(function () {
    $('#one').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
        $('#one').fadeTo(2000, 0, function() {
            $('#two').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
                $('#two').fadeTo(2000, 0, function() {
                    $('#three').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
                        $('#three').fadeTo(2000, 0, function() {
                            $('#four').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
                                $('#four').fadeTo(2000, 0,  function() {
                                    $('#five').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
                                        $('#five').fadeTo(2000, 0, function() {
                                            $('#six').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
                                                $('#six').fadeTo(2000, 0, function() {
                                                    $('#seven').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
                                                        $('#seven').fadeTo(2000, 0, function() {
                                                            $('#eight').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {
                                                                $('#eight').fadeTo(2000, 0);         
                                                            }); 
                                                        });        
                                                    });            
                                                });            
                                            });         
                                        });          
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Any idea how to prettify / shorten this function?

Comment: Function is perfect; ship it! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all the elements follow the same behaviour (ie. fade in for two seconds, then out for two seconds) you can queue all the animations in a loop, delayed iteratively by four seconds on each successive element.

To make that simpler, you can apply a common class to them all. Something like this:

```js
$('span[data-i18n="text.about"]').click(function() {
  $('.fade-queue').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 4000).queue(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(2000, 1).dequeue();
    }).queue(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo(2000, 0).dequeue();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div { 
  opacity: 0; 
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-i18n="text.about">Click me</span>

<div class="fade-queue" id="one">One</div>
<div class="fade-queue" id="two">Two</div>
<div class="fade-queue" id="three">Three</div>
<div class="fade-queue" id="four">Four</div>
<div class="fade-queue" id="five">Five</div>
<div class="fade-queue" id="six">Six</div>
<div class="fade-queue" id="seven">Seven</div>
<div class="fade-queue" id="eight">Eight</div>
```

Also note that this method no longer relies on the `id` attributes at all. As such it's much easier to maintain and extend, as you can just add more `<div class="fade-queue">` elements to your HTML without needing to change any JS code.

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help